# How to assign weight to the regression model (linear and non-linear)

Tags: r

The dataset consists of many price points from different sources. For the same item number, the prices are widely spread. The dependent variable is the price, independent variables are quantity and some other variables. It is obvious that some price points are closer to the mean and within 1 standard deviation. I would like to give more weight to the prices which are closer to the mean or within 1 standard deviation in each group (same item number). In other words, I want to give the least weight to the $50 of item_no_1 and $3000 to Item_No_5. $50 and $3000 cannot be removed because they are a valid price not a outlier. How can I do it in R with regression models(linear, KNN, random forest,etc)?

```
Item_No_1 $5 
Item_No_1 $10 
Item_No_1 $5.5 
Item_No_1 $5.5 
Item_No_1 $5 
Item_No_1 $5 
Item_No_1 $4.8 
Item_No_1 $5.4 
Item_No_1 $50
Item_No_5 $300
Item_No_5 $400
Item_No_5 $600
Item_No_5 $3000
Item_No_5 $1200
```

Comment: Many R modelling functions (lm, glm, lmer) have a `weights` argument. Careful with using binomial glms though. ;)

Comment: I get the sense that you are not yet ready for regression modeling. You have data in a form that would be difficult to work with. I think you need to study some tutorial material focusing on data types and the mechanism for reading files.